# Docker - gaining access to internet after declaring static ip address

Tags: docker

I have set static ip-address,gateway and netmask in my interface file located in /etc/network folder. The docker command I us to run my container is docker run -it -p 192.16X.X.XX:10940:10940 mycontainer. When I run my container everything works the way it should except I'm unable to access the internet from within the container. Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  How did you build your image, what command doesn't work, and what error do you get?  Is the network configuration just the host's network setup, or have you tried to push it into Docker space somehow?

Comment: Steps to recreate: Change interface file in path provided above to include ipaddress, gateway and subnetmask. Once that is done run any container and try accessing the internet for example apt-get update. ERROR: Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:http: